# Is it possible to open azure portal resource link not in the default Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

For user who has access to multiple directories (see screen shot below)

[image]

For azure web app I can generate link like below:

https://ms.portal.azure.com/#resource/{resourceId}/DeploymentSource

If the resource is in my default Directory, I can paste the link to the browser and it will open the right blade.

If I paste a link to a resource that is not in the default directory for the user, then I get the following:

[image]

However, If I first got to the root of portal.azure.com and switch directory to the targt webapp, then paste the link to the blade, then it works.

Is this possible to tell  azure portal to switch directory based on the resource in question. Btw, this is for code that we are writing that is running outside the azure portal hosting frame (hence the desire to open specific blade for a given web app)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is now possible by adding `@directory-domain.com/` after the hash. For example, `https://portal.azure.com/#resource/{resourceId}/DeploymentSource` under a directory with the `stackoverflow.com` domain becomes `https://portal.azure.com/#@stackoverflow.com/resource/{resourceId}/DeploymentSource`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Azure does **not** support this at this time.

You could give your feedback to this [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal/suggestions/6239996-choose-default-directory), all of the feedback you share in this link will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams.

Also I have vote this feedback. Your understanding and support will be highly appreciated.

Comment: For now, Azure does not support this, I have vote this feedback. Please feel free to let me know if you need further assistance. if it helpful, please don't forget to accept it as an answer, thanks:)